# Imported functions and working with two .js files

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I have created a server with fireBase and I am practicing, I have managed to create some boxes, one to create an entry to the server and when you press the button it is recorded in firebase and also appears in the DOM, then when it appears in this you have two buttons, one that deletes the input and another one that I want to update the data through "inputs" but I can't get the latter to work because I don't know how to collect the values. if I didn't create the inputs I could do it from the first collection but that's not the idea, let's see if you can guide me on the right path!!!

```js
//Me traigo mi db firestore
import { getTasks, insertTask, deleteTask, updateTask} from "./utils.js";
//console.log(db);
//Extraigo todos los documentos de tasks y creo tarjetas con ellos
getTasks();


//Obtenemos el form y capturamos el submit
const form = document.getElementById("task-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const task = {
        title: form["task-title"].value,
        description: form["task-description"].value
    }

    insertTask(task);
})


const buttonsCardD = document.getElementsByName("delete");
buttonsCardD.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var divDelete = element.parentNode.parentNode;
        document.body.removeChild(divDelete);
        //console.log("Estoy borrando la tarea: "+element.id);
        deleteTask(element.id);
    })
});

const buttonsCardA = document.getElementsByName('añadir');
const inputNam = document.getElementsByName('formulario')
buttonsCardA.forEach(element => {
   
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const taskIn = {
            title: inputNam["tituloTar"].value,
            description: inputNam["descriptionTar"].value
        }
       
        updateTask(element.id, taskIn);
    })
});
```

```html
<body>
        <div style="position: relative; left: 484px;" ><h1>Ingresa aqui la tarea</h1></div>
        <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-6  offset-md-4" style="max-width: 20rem;display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
            <div class="card-header">Formulario Tareas</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="task-form">
                    <input type="text" id="task-title" class="form-control" placeholder="Título de la tarea"
                        autofocus>
                    <textarea id="task-description" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción de la tarea" cols="10"
                        rows="5"></textarea>
                    <br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Tarea" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="task-button">

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h3>Listado de tareas existente</h3>

        <script src="utils.js" type="module" defer></script>
        <script src="index.js" type="module" defer></script>
    </body>
```

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, doc, setDoc, deleteDoc,updateDoc } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "task"));

function createCard(id, task, ) {
    //<div class="card text-white bg-info mb-6  offset-md-4" style="max-width: 20rem;">
    const principalDiv = document.createElement('div');
    principalDiv.setAttribute("class", "card bg-light mb-3");
    principalDiv.style = "max-width: 20rem;";
    principalDiv.setAttribute("name", id);
    principalDiv.setAttribute("id", id);
    //<div class="card-header">Formulario Tareas</div>
    const headerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const contentDiv = document.createTextNode("Id: " + id);
    headerDiv.setAttribute("class", "card-header");

    headerDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    principalDiv.appendChild(headerDiv);
    // <div class="card-body">
    const bodyDiv = document.createElement('form');
    bodyDiv.setAttribute("name", "formulario")
    const pTitle = document.createElement("p");
    const pTitleText = document.createTextNode("Title: " + task.title);


    const pTitleInText = document.createElement("input");
    pTitleInText.type = "text";
    pTitleInText.value =  task.title ;
    pTitleInText.placeholder = "Modifica Titulo";
    pTitleInText.setAttribute("name", "tituloTar");
   


    // const pTitleIn = document.createTextNode('placeholder' + task.title);
    const hr = document.createElement('hr');
    const pDesc = document.createElement("p");
    const pDescText = document.createTextNode("Description: " + task.description);


    const pDescInText = document.createElement("input");
    pDescInText.type = "text";
    pDescInText.value = task.description;
    pDescInText.placeholder = "Modifica Descripción";
    pDescInText.setAttribute("name", "descriptionTar");
  


    pTitle.appendChild(pTitleText);
    // pTitleIn.appendChild(pTitleInText)
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pTitle);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pTitleInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);
    pDesc.appendChild(pDescText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pDesc);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pDescInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);

    var inputAdd = document.createElement('input');
    inputAdd.type = "button";
    inputAdd.value = "Añadir";
    inputAdd.setAttribute("name", "añadir");
    inputAdd.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(inputAdd)


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "button";
    input.value = "Borrar Tarea";
    input.class = "btn";
    input.setAttribute("name", "delete");
    input.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(input);

    principalDiv.appendChild(bodyDiv);

    document.body.appendChild(principalDiv);
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);

}

export function getTasks() {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        createCard(doc.id, doc.data());
    });
}
function generateRandomIdTask(num) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
}
export async function insertTask(task) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "task", generateRandomIdTask(20)), task);
    alert("Insertada la tarea: " + task.title);
}

export async function deleteTask(id) {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "task", id));
    alert("Borrada la tarea: " + id);
}

export async function updateTask(id, task){
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "task", id),task);
    location.reload()
    alert("Actaulaización: " + id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some improvements and now I can get the program to work as I wish.

```js
//Me traigo mi db firestore
import { getTasks, insertTask, deleteTask, updateTask} from "./utils.js";
//console.log(db);
//Extraigo todos los documentos de tasks y creo tarjetas con ellos
getTasks();


//Obtenemos el form y capturamos el submit
const form = document.getElementById("task-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const task = {
        title: form["task-title"].value,
        description: form["task-description"].value
    }

    insertTask(task);
})


const buttonsCardD = document.getElementsByName("delete");
buttonsCardD.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var divDelete = element.parentNode.parentNode;
        document.body.removeChild(divDelete);
        //console.log("Estoy borrando la tarea: "+element.id);
        deleteTask(element.id);
    })
});

const buttonsCardA = document.getElementsByName('añadir');



buttonsCardA.forEach(element => {
    const inputNam = document.getElementsByName(element.id)
    
       
  
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(document.querySelector('.tituloTar').value)
        
        
        const taskIn = {
            title: document.querySelector('.tituloTar').value,
            description: document.querySelector('.descriptionTar').value
            
        }
       
        updateTask(element.id, taskIn);
        // updateTask(element.id, taskIn);
    })
});
```

With these last touches, I only have to make it more attractive for the user

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, doc, setDoc, deleteDoc,updateDoc } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "task"));

function createCard(id, task, i) {
    //<div class="card text-white bg-info mb-6  offset-md-4" style="max-width: 20rem;">
    const principalDiv = document.createElement('div');
    principalDiv.setAttribute("class", "card bg-light mb-3");
    principalDiv.style = "max-width: 20rem;";
    principalDiv.setAttribute("name", id);
    principalDiv.setAttribute("id", i);
    //<div class="card-header">Formulario Tareas</div>
    const headerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const contentDiv = document.createTextNode("Id: " + id);
    headerDiv.setAttribute("class", "card-header");

    headerDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    principalDiv.appendChild(headerDiv);
    // <div class="card-body">
    const bodyDiv = document.createElement('form');
    bodyDiv.setAttribute("name", "formulario")
    bodyDiv.setAttribute("class", "formulario")
    // const pTitle = document.createElement("p");
    // const pTitleText = document.createTextNode("Title: " + task.title);


    const pTitleInText = document.createElement("input");
    pTitleInText.type = "text";
    pTitleInText.value =  task.title ;
    // pTitleInText.placeholder = "Modifica Titulo";
    pTitleInText.setAttribute("name", "tituloTar");
    pTitleInText.setAttribute("class", "tituloTar");
   


    // const pTitleIn = document.createTextNode('placeholder' + task.title);
    const hr = document.createElement('hr');
    // const pDesc = document.createElement("p");
    // const pDescText = document.createTextNode("Description: " + task.description);


    const pDescInText = document.createElement("input");
    pDescInText.type = "text";
    pDescInText.value = task.description;
    // pDescInText.placeholder = "Modifica Descripción";
    pDescInText.setAttribute("name", "descriptionTar");
    pDescInText.setAttribute("class", "descriptionTar");
  


   
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pTitleInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);
  
    bodyDiv.appendChild(pDescInText);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(hr);

    var inputAdd = document.createElement('input');
    inputAdd.type = "button";
    inputAdd.value = "Modificar";
    inputAdd.setAttribute("name", "añadir");
    inputAdd.setAttribute("class", "boton");
    inputAdd.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(inputAdd)


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "button";
    input.value = "Borrar Tarea";
   
    input.setAttribute("name", "delete");
    input.setAttribute("class", "boton");
    input.setAttribute("id", id);
    bodyDiv.appendChild(input);

    principalDiv.appendChild(bodyDiv);

    document.body.appendChild(principalDiv);
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);

}

export function getTasks() {
    let i = 0;
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // console.log(doc.id);
        createCard(doc.id, doc.data(), i);
        i++
    });
}


function generateRandomIdTask(num) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
}
export async function insertTask(task) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "task", generateRandomIdTask(20)), task);
    location.reload()
    alert("Insertada la tarea: " + task.title);
}

export async function deleteTask(id) {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "task", id));
    alert("Borrada la tarea: " + id);
}

export async function updateTask(id, task){
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "task", id),task);
    location.reload()
    alert("Actaulaización: " + id);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).